# OnClickListener for a custom ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, onclicklistener

This is my first android project so please help
I am trying to create an on click listener for my listview. I will have multiple listview so i cannot name my listview as android:id="@id/android:list". Well i can display data but i am not able to implement an onClickListener Method. I dont want to click on the textview or any button in the list view i want to click the whole list view while passing the value to the new activity

This is the main activity that starts when the applicaton is launched.

```
public class Db extends Activity {
private SQLiteDatabase newDb;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
public ListAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
    openDatabase();
    newDb = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();   
    Cursor c = newDb.rawQuery("SELECT _id, organisation, address, postcode FROM shoplist", null);
    int i_organisation = c.getColumnIndex("organisation");
    int i_id = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int i_address = c.getColumnIndex("address");
    int i_postcode = c.getColumnIndex("postcode");

    //int count = c.getCount();
    //String data[] = new String[count];
    //int i= 0;
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        String i1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String i2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("organisation"));
        String i3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
        results.add(i1);

        //i++;
    }
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.main, results, results, results);
    setListAdapter(adapter);





}

private long inserttodata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", "112");
    cv.put("organisation","test" );
     return newDb.insert("shoplist", null, cv);
}

private void openDatabase() {

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();


    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
System.out.println("failed to open");
        throw sqle;

    }
    //String[] columns= new String[]{"_id", "Organisation"};
    //cursor = newDb.query("Shop", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

}

}
```

My database helper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/calc.three/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "charity.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory c = null;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, c , SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}}
```

My custom adapter class

```
 public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
static List<String> serialNo = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();  
static List<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();

Context myContext;

public customAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> c_serialNo,
    List<String> c_name, List<String> c_address) {

super(context, resource, c_serialNo);

myContext = context;
serialNo = c_serialNo;
name = c_name;
address = c_address;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) myContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
}

TextView tv_serialNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serialNo);
TextView tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView tv_address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);

if (tv_serialNo != null) {
    tv_serialNo.setText(serialNo.get(position));
}
if (tv_name != null) {
    tv_name.setText(name.get(position));
}
if (tv_address!= null) {
    tv_address.setText(address.get(position));
}

return v; }}
```

The main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@id/android:list"></ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

The custom_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">



        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/serialNo"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:gravity="top"                    
                android:text="sn"
                                    />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:gravity="top"                    
                android:text="name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/serialNo"
                                    />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fav"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:padding="1dip"

                android:text="name"
                android:layout_below="@id/serialNo"
                                    />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/source"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/address"
                android:src="@drawable/pg" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `OnItemClickListener` for list items, applies to the ListView, instead of trying to apply an `OnClickListener` to the cells themselves.

`theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener(...){...});`